# Detect Narrow Line in very noise image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, detection, noise

I have performed preprocessing steps in an noisy acoustic image and now I need to detect narrow black lines.

Can you think of a better way to detect these lines?

[image]

[image]

My goal is to detect the line in the red box in this image.

[image]

Comment: Please add a further image showing what you want to detect.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I answered below.

Comment: [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

**Failed Answer**: - This is not a perfect solution but will require further work to make it robust for various images. I noticed that there is very less noise in the black lines, and thus Canny does not found a lot of edges within this region. Code and results below:-

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('2.png')
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,10,60,apertureSize = 7)
cv2.imwrite('2-1-edges-10-60.jpg',edges)

kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
closeEdges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('2-2-edges-10-60-dilated-1.jpg',closeEdges)

invertEdges = 255 - closeEdges
cv2.imwrite('2-3-invertedges-10-60.jpg',invertEdges)

minLineLength=100
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=invertEdges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=200,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=80)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    cv2.line(gray, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imwrite('2-4-houghlines.jpg',gray)
```

[image: Output1]

[image: Output2]

Using connected component on inverse of output image and finding maximum size elements could be helpful.

Another way of approaching this is use of gradient image and directly finding area of small range of gradient magnitude. This approach would be much more flexible as it will not require using fixed threshold values - 10 and 60 as above. Threshold values can be adaptive according to image gradient/you can normalize gradient of image before using hard-coded thresholds.

**Better Answer(30-40% accurate)**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os

# Store all images in this folder
path='images-1'

def autocrop(image, threshold=0):
    if len(image.shape) == 3:
        flatImage = np.max(image, 2)
    else:
        flatImage = image

    rows = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 0) > threshold)[0]
    if rows.size:
        cols = np.where(np.max(flatImage, 1) > threshold)[0]
        image = image[cols[0]: cols[-1] + 1, rows[0]: rows[-1] + 1]
    else:
        image = image[:1, :1]
    return image

def skeleton(img):
    size = np.size(img)
    skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)

    element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
    done = False

    while( not done):
        eroded = cv2.erode(img,element)
        temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
        temp = cv2.subtract(img,temp)
        skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
        img = eroded.copy()

        zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(img)
        if zeros==size:
            done = True

    return skel

def gamma_correction(img, correction):
    img = img/255.0
    img = cv2.pow(img, correction)
    return np.uint8(img*255)

def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)
    # apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

    # return the edged image
    return edged

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.endswith(".png"):
        current = os.path.join(path, file)
        img = cv2.imread(current, 0)
        print 'processing ' + current
        img = autocrop(img, 0)
        cv2.imwrite(current + '-0-cropped.jpg', img)
        height, width = img.shape[:2]
        img = cv2.resize(img, (width, width))
        cv2.imwrite(current + '-0-resized.jpg', img)

        # cv2.imwrite(current +'-2-auto_canny_default.jpg', auto_canny(img))
        # img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
        # cv2.imwrite(current +'-0-medianBlur.jpg',img)
        # th3 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(img,255,cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
        # cv2.imwrite(current +'-1-threshold_gaussian.jpg',th3)

        # laplacian = cv2.Laplacian(img,cv2.CV_64F)
        # cv2.imwrite(current + '-3-threshold_gaussian.jpg', laplacian)

        #img = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, 3, 3, 5)
        edges = cv2.Canny(img,10,20,apertureSize = 5)
        cv2.imwrite(current +'-1-edges-10-60.jpg',edges)

        kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
        edges = cv2.morphologyEx(edges, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
        cv2.imwrite(current +'-1-edgesClosed-10-60.jpg', edges)

        edges = 255-edges
        cv2.imwrite(current +'-2-edgesClosedInverted-10-60.jpg', edges)
        im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edges, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        imgColor = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        maxArea = 0
        for cnt in contours:
            if maxArea < cv2.contourArea(cnt):
                maxArea = cv2.contourArea(cnt)

        for cnt in contours:
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)       #I have used min Area rect for better result
            width = rect[1][0]
            height = rect[1][1]
            if cv2.contourArea(cnt) > int(maxArea/2.5) and ( width < height/2 or height < width/2): 
                cv2.drawContours(imgColor, cnt, -1, (0,255,0), 1)
        cv2.imwrite(current+'-5-Contours.jpg',imgColor)


        # edges = skeleton(255-edges)
        # cv2.imwrite(current +'-2-skeleton.jpg', edges)
        # edges = 255-edges
        # minLineLength=int(width/4)
        # threshold = 20
        # maxLineGap = 1
        # rho = 1
        # lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=edges,rho=rho,theta=np.pi/180, threshold=threshold,lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=maxLineGap)

        # if lines is not None:
        #     a,b,c = lines.shape
        #     for i in range(a):
        #         cv2.line(img, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #         cv2.line(edges, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
        #     cv2.imwrite(current+'-5-houghlines.jpg',img)
        #     cv2.imwrite(current+'-6-houghlines.jpg',edges)
        #     print 'cool'
        # else:
        #     cv2.imwrite(current+'-5-houghlines.jpg',img)
```

Also, do check following links:

1. [Detection of Continuous, Smooth and Thin Edges in Noisy Images Using Constrained Particle Swarm Optimisation](https://www.lri.fr/~hansen/proceedings/2011/GECCO/proceedings/p45.pdf)
2. http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14491
3. http://answers.opencv.org/question/3454/detecting-thick-edges/

Comment: Beware: Run this code on a large dataset to see how well it does, before using this approach and refining it.

Comment: HI @saurabheights, thanks for your help, but the performance is not good on a large dataset. I think RANSAC fit line would be a better idea.

Comment: @RômuloCerqueira: I thought so too, which is why I had very low confidence from the start. On a large variation, this approach may not generalize properly. Could you upload few sample images where it failed, preferably on dropbox? Also, what's the accuracy over random some 100 samples, just to know whether improving current approach is a good idea? I will try to work on this, but I have a deadline and might not pick it in coming few(4-5) days, but will add it to the todo list(to not forget).

Comment: @RômuloCerqueira: I am not well-versed with Ransac, but I think it is used to do model fitting, however Hough transform should fit the role currently with your needs of straight-line fit. If you could provide failed test images, I might be able to test and see Ransac and Hough both. Of course, will be aware of not overfitting but will try for more general approach. Also, try to upload atleast 10 failed images to understand the nature of captured images.

Comment: Hi @saurabheights, sorry for my delay. I have performed some preprocessed steps in the noisy images, however I still have problems to detect the lines (and not detect when it is not present). I upload a dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6r2gaio5h9ichk7/dataset.rar?dl=0). I will be greatful if you can help me.

Comment: @RômuloCerqueira: Hi Romulo, I am currently quite busy and won't be able to make time(probably till 1 May), but just wanted to confirm that I have downloaded the dataset and added it to my todo list. I have checked the dataset as well. There are quite a few images where the line is highly indistinguishable from the background and would require adaptive thresholding of gradient(not sure if gradient is the only possible answer). Also, I didnt see any images where there is no line as you pointed in previous comment. If you could provide those images, it would be great.

Comment: Hi @saurabheights, sorry for my delay during the Easter. I uploaded a new dataset [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/30h5bzb4eraqezg/dataset2.rar?dl=0) with some logs without the desired line, only the background (index 4650 to 4800). I will work on the problem in this week. If you have a time to take a look on that, I will be very grateful. In addition, thanks for your comments.

Comment: Hi @saurabheights, I will be greatful if you can help me with this topic here.

Comment: @RômuloCerqueira: Please see my updated answer. It does provide a little better accuracy. Since, contour can be easily analyzed for shape and there are only few contours, finding the line should not be difficult. To be honest, it's not much better but I can not impart more time as of now. If you had read my earlier reply(deleted now), it mentions why I have been so busy. Also, I have added a few links.

Comment: In Imagemagick forum link, I think it would be much easier to see if it works. Do sobel edge detection on an image pyramid(resize down by 1.1), and then upscale each sobel edge image by 1.1 times and merge(add and divide by 2). Make sure to calculate in double.

Comment: @RômuloCerqueira: Is it ok to ask what this work is about?